# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are odd positive integers, then there are integers s and t such that $a = bs + t$ where |t| < b, and t is either zero or odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if *a* and *b* are **odd** positive integers, then there are integers *s* and *t* such that $$a = bs + t,$$ where $|t| \lt b$, and $t$ is either **zero** or **odd**.

Comment: I tried showing 2 cases: one where _t = o_ and the other when _t_ is of the form _2j + 1_. Then, using the fact that _a_ and _b_ are of similar form (because they are both odd), I tried showing that _a = bs + t_ can be written as an odd number on both sides. But I'm doing something wrong, I think, and also wondering if assuming _t_ is positive and finding a contradiction in the assumption that _a_ is odd would be better.

Comment: Do you already have available the [division with remainder theorem?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

Comment: Yes. Does that mean my approach to proving this problem is completely wrong?

Comment: i know you already have an accepted answer, but this comment is for future readers: the case where t=0 must be removed, because we are given $b \nmid a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the Division Algorithm, there are $s,t$ such that $a = bs+t$ with $\,t \in [0,b\!-\!1]$. If $\,t\ne0\,$ is even then $a = b(s\!+\!1)+t-b,\,$ for $\,t\!-\!b \in [-(b\!-\!1),0],\,$ and $t$ even, $b$ odd $\Rightarrow$ $t-b$ odd.

i.e. if the remainder $\, t\ = a\ {\rm mod}\ b = 2n \ne  0,\,$ toggle its parity by replacing it by $\,t\!-\!b\equiv t\!\!\ \pmod b$.

Comment: I understand the first sentence and why _t_ even with _b_ odd implies that _t-b_ is odd, but would you mind explaining why you chose _a = b(s+1) + t-b_ for the condition you gave? In particular, how did you know to chose _t-b_ to be in [-(b-1),0]. Also, do we even use the fact that _a_ is odd?

Comment: @XxGaMbiT The goal is to choose an integer $t\equiv a\pmod b$ that is odd if nonzero and as small as possible, i.e. $|t| < b$. If the least nonnegative such $t$ doesn't work (i.e. is even $\ne 0),$ then there is only one other choice for $t$ in the sought interval $(-b, b),$ namely $\,t-b,\,$ and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$S=\{a-nb:n\in\mathbb Z\}$$

there exists a unique $N\in\mathbb Z$  such that

$$0 \leq a-Nb \lt b$$

If $ a-Nb$  is odd or zero, let $s=N,t=a-Nb$. otherwise, let $s=N+1, t=a-(N+1)b$

Comment: Probably want "if $a-sb$ is odd or zero..."

Comment: en. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking at this problem right now. I am a bit confused. We know that both $a$ and $b$ are odd and by the division algorithm we have that $a=b\cdot s + t$ where $b>0$ and $0\le t< b$. Consider $a=b\cdot s + t$. Since $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then we may consider two cases:

1. $s$ is even
2. $s$ is odd

If 1., then clearly $t$ has to be either odd or $=0$. If 2., then either $t=0$ or $t$ is even!? Since if we assume that $s$, $a$ and $b$ are odd then we may write $$a=b\cdot s + t=(2n+1)(2j+1)+t=\bigl[ 2\cdot (2nj+n+j)+1 \bigr]+t,$$ so $t$ must be either $=0$ or even whenever $a$ is odd. Is this correct? Because if it is, then it is not true that $t=0$ or $t$ is odd (?).